# Find an object's position based on a specified attribute in an arraylist

Tags: c#, arraylist

I have a small problem:

```
class Swimmer
{
   private string name;
   private string province;
   private int age;
   private int[] times;

   public Swimmer(string name, string province, int age, int[] times)
   {
       this.name = name;
       this.province = province;
       this.age = age;
       this.times = times;
   }
```

followed by other methods and get and set methods too

```
class Swimmers
{
    ArrayList AllSwimmers;

    public Swimmers()
    {
        AllSwimmers = new ArrayList();
    }

//some other methods in between

    public int GetOnName()
    {
        int pos = -1;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the swimmer");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        AllSwimmers.Sort();

        pos = AllSwimmers.BinarySearch(AllSwimmers) ;

        Console.WriteLine(pos) ;

        return pos;

    }
```

Based on the Swimmer, I want to enter a swimmer's name and the method `GetOnName()` needs to do a binary search for the swimmer's name. I do not know what to pass as the BinarySearch parameter, the parameter is `ArrayList.BinarySearch(Object value)`, I have heard something of type casting but I can't figure out how to solve this problem.

For instance:

User input = Johnny

somewhere in the arraylist is Johnny with his age, state, etc.

I want to find Johnny in the arraylist and display all of his data

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [`List<Swimmer>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) instead of `ArrayList`.  This will allow you to simply use:

```
pos = AllSwimmers.FindIndex(s => s.Name == name);
```

Note that this will require adding a `Name` property to your `Swimmer` class which is public:

```
public string Name { get { return this.name; } }
```

There are many advantages to using `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList`.  In addition to supporting more features, it's also completely type safe (you can't add something that isn't a "Swimmer" to a `List<Swimmer>`).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, FindIndex performs a linear search, rather than binary. Can you show how a binary search would be done? Does it require the use Comparators? Thanks.

Comment: @user1467261 You can use `List<T>.BinarySearch` if you prefer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh.aspx) but it requires you to sort the list, which makes it more expensive in most cases than a linear search.

Comment: @user1467261 Doing a sort to avoid a linear search will hurt your performance, not help it...

Comment: I've added a `BinarySearch` example.

Answer (score 0):

You should switch from [`ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) (an outdated pre-generics class) to [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) (same idea: a list backed by an array, but way better with generics). It's also [good practice](http://forums.asp.net/t/1231995.aspx), in general, to program to an interface like `IList<T>` instead of a specific class, like `ArrayList` or `List<T>`. And this problem can be solved easily with LINQ, (especially if you want the object, not the index) not with a binary search (which requires the list to be sorted on the attribute you want to search by).

```
IList<Swimmer> AllSwimmers;

public Swimmers()
{
    AllSwimmers = new List<Swimmer>();
}

...

string name = Console.ReadLine();
Swimmer swimmer = AllSwimmers.Single(x => x.Name == name);
return swimmer;
// or, if you really want the index, remove the above line and continue with:
int pos = AllSwimmers.IndexOf(swimmer);
return pos;
```

You should look up the difference between `Where`, `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Single`, and `SingleOrDefault` (all extension methods defined in [`Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx), usable on any `IEnumerable<T>`) and choose whichever makes the most sense based on your specific instance.

For reasonably-sized collections, the linear searches of LINQ extension methods are a good choice. If you have a very large list and can sort it once and then you'll be doing a lot of searches on it, then it might be a good idea to use a binary search. (or if you're just trying to do a binary search for academic reasons, e.g. that's your homework assignment) Then you can use `List<T>.BinarySearch` after sorting the list appropriately. You'll need an `IComparer<Swimmer>` that compares the names.

```
// we're using methods on List<T> now, can't use the interface IList<T>
List<Swimmer> AllSwimmers;
IComparer<Swimmer> nameComparer = new NameComparer();

// make sure it's sorted first
// only need to do this when you add/remove/change items
AllSwimmers.Sort(nameComparer);

// then when you're doing the binary search
int pos = AllSwimmers.BinarySearch(new Swimmer { Name = name }, nameComparer);

// NameComparer class left as an exercise
```

Comment: If you plan to keep your list sorted, you could just use a `SortedList` instead.